# Find python package documentation in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-packaging

Is there a way to access python module / package documentation in jupyter notebook, similar to function documentations.

help(round), len? or ?len works. Looking for something like help(pandas)...

Comment: Does this cover what you are looking for? https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.01-help-and-documentation.html

Comment: Not quite. It only covers functions and objects, not modules and it's properties / attributes.